# Can't get Meek PT's or IPv6 addresses?

Tags: bridge, meek, ipv6

When I visit the BridgeDB I noticed there's no longer an option to select a Meek PT bridge. I also find that whenever I try to get a find bridges with an IPv6 address, I can't get any results no matter which type of bridge I select. I considered emailing bridges@torproject.org however they only accepts emails from Gmail, Yahoo, and Riseup. I don't want to sign up for Gmail or Yahoo because it would require me to allow JavaScript and my phone number, and I'm unable to get an account with Riseup since they're an invite-only service.

So how should I go about getting Meek Pluggable Transports and bridges with IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 0):

It really strange, but I guess [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/) doesn't give bridges with meek transports anymore. Neither on their website or on their mail.
You still have a lot of other pluggable transports such as `fte`, `obfs3`, `obfs4` *(usually the way to go)* and `scramblesuit`. You can get them all with IPv6 addresses. You should try to use one of them.